# Guidelines on reviewing de-spamination tag wiki edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, spam

Tonight I came across [this tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6210791) for `Mimosa`.

At the time I write this, the edit was approved, but also disputed by two edit-reviewers as vandalism, possibly because the edit removes most of the features of Mimosa and reduces the description to simply

> Mimosa is a build tool for JavaScript

If I could have edited, I might have kept some of the features but eliminated the ad copy tone. I also didn't like the word "build", since it isn't like JS typically gets run through `make` or `ant`. But I only had an Approve/Reject choice.  So, after checking mimosa's home page, I chose "Approve".

The original excerpt is a little spammy, with phrases like "built right in" to describe library support and "Pluggable for authoring your own functionality."  Really?  So that's why it is pluggable?  I'd never have guessed.

But this made me think of `emacs`, an editor with numerous features found nowhere else, like pong, and psychoanalyze-pinhead.

Emacs tag description reads as follows:

> About emacs GNU Emacs is an extensible, customizable text editor.
>   Begun in the mid-1970s as a set of macros on top of TECO, it was
>   re-written using C and Emacs Lisp to provide portability and an
>   extendable interface. It continues to be actively developed today.
>
> Emacs provides context-sensitive editing modes with syntax coloring,
>   is self documenting, has full Unicode support and extensions to do
>   almost anything. Die-hard Emacs users do most everything from within
>   Emacs: write, compile, run and debug code; read/compose email; browse
>   the web; do project planning etc. Some other editors, like Visual
>   Studio or Eclipse provide Emacs keybindings.

If I reduced that to

> Emacs is a text editor with an embedded Lisp interpreter and applications

I assume that wouldn't be appreciated much at all.  But `emacs` also has a long standing history in the free software movement, stetching over several decades.  Still, if it wasn't `emacs` some of this description could be considered spammy, such as "do almost anything".

Back to `Mimosa`, it appears that while the excerpt might have been fixed, there is still work to do with the main body of the tag.  It still reads a lot like ad copy.  The most [recent edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1600500) has "typo" as the edit reason but in addition to fixing a typo, more ad-copy-like material is inserted into the code by an established user (3k+).  A typo was fixed "mismosa", but that typo was created by the initial user establishing the wiki with more ad-copy-like material in [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/962714).

So I think I did the right thing with `mimosa` but am unsure what the general guidelines should be for approving or rejecting similar tag wiki edits in the future.

Comment: The words "baby" and "bathwater" come to mind.

Comment: Does it bear stating that the [tag:emacs] tag wiki *excerpt* (as was edited for [tag:mimosa]) is markedly shorter than it's full description, reproduced here?

Comment: I might have rejected for "Simply defining what a [tag] *is* rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name *itself* is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe **why** and **when** a tag should be used."

Comment: @femtoRgon Yes, my mistake.  Maybe `emacs` is not a relevant example after all. Mulling deleting the emacs paragraph.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Yes, that's why I posted the question. Throwing out the baby certainly comes to mind on a few audit reviews that discourage editing "spam" as a waste of time (i.e. if you choose edit, you fail the audit), where the spam was merely a bad choice of wording used by someone offering their *free, open source library* as a solution to a problem.  I would certainly be more keen to throw out large portions of a spammy tag description or tag excerpt for a commercial product.